# TCP checksum calculation for divert socket

Tags: c, tcp, ip, freebsd, checksum

I have a divert socket. I am trying to change the port on packets as I see them. When I do this - do I need to recalculate the TCP checksum, and the IP checksum?

I am trying to do this, but I am seeing reset packets in tcpdump. I dont know if this is because I am calculating the tcp checksum wrong, or if its something else going on.

I used the cksum methods from this site:

http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/

I thought with using a divert socket, if I change one thing, it should be fairly straightforward, but doesnt seem to be. is there a TCP checksum calculator out there I can use to verify I am getting the right value?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to recompute the checksum. Here is a description of the calculation: [TCP/IP Checksum calculation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ip-header-checksum/)

Answer (score 0):

See Section 3.3 of [RFC 1631](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1631.txt) for the checksum adjustments that a NAT/PAT must make. You don't have to go through the entire packet, you just need to adjust the checksum based on the bytes that you modify.

Comment: Interesting. In their C function, do you know specifically what the args old pointer and new pointer refer to? Do I just need to create two variables that have the old and new data in them?

Comment: `optr` points to what you're removing from the old packet and nptr points to what you're inserting in the new packet.  So if you're just changing the port number, optr points to the original port, nptr points to the replacement port. You could use two variables, or one could point to the location in the packet.

Comment: Ah ok - that makes sense. I wasn't sure if I needed to have a whole copy of the old packet and the the packet.

Comment: Thought I made that clear in the answer when I said "you don't have to go through the entire packet". The nice thing about a checksum is that if you change one byte, the checksum just changes by the difference between the old and new byte. Algorithms like CRC and MD5 provide better integrity checks, but they're more expensive and don't have this simple property.